# How to do a while ( x < y ) in jinja2

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

How should I do a while ( x < y ) in jinja2?
I've seen the jinja2 docs, it seems like they only support for loop for a declared variable of array and while() is not supported at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your closest alternative with *Jinja2* would be to use a *for* with *range*:

```
  {% range number from 3 to 6 %}
      {{ number }}
      (...)
  {% endrange %}
```

And you can pass the variables from your program to use them in the loop.

Comment: yea, that seems to be the case. Thanks for the aid