# Use Jinja Variable to generate n elements

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to use Jinja variables to generate n options in a drop down.  Here is an example:

```
    Session Select: <br>
    {{ sessions }}
    <select style="color:black">
        {% for session in sessions %}
            <li>{{ session }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </select> <br><br>
```

The value of sessions is:

['Session 1', 'Session 2', 'Session 3']

Any thoughts?

Comment: So you are looking for the html code for a dropdown?

Comment: Nah, I have the html code for the drop down.  I want to iterate through n number of sessions, which is provided by the flask template

Comment: What is wrong with your code? I don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `no_sessions` is your `n` value... I would try something like this:

```
Session Select: <br>
<select style="color:black">
    {% range number from 1 to no_sessions %}
        <option>Session {{ number }}</option>
    {% endrange %}
</select> <br><br>
```

[(related to this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668025/how-to-do-a-while-x-y-in-jinja2)

Answer (score 0):

To generate items within a select box you use the `<option>` tag, not `<li>`.

Comment: I do not think this is what he asks.

Comment: Very likely not. But he hasn't bothered to explain what he *is* asking, so until then all we can do is correct the obvious errors in his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session Select: <br>
<select style="color:black">
    {% for session in sessions %}
        <option value="{{ session }}">{{ session }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select> <br><br>
```